# Cannot use dex2jar on my mac: permission denied

Tags: android, dex2jar

I downloaded dex2jar and now trying to use it, but if I type 'sh d2j-dex2jar.sh' it shows the following message.

```
d2j-dex2jar.sh: line 36: ./d2j_invoke.sh: Permission denied
```

At first I thought that the permission was denied because the programme required the root permission, so I also tried adding 'sudo' to the command, and it did not work either. How should I solve this problem?

Comment: You probably need to provide the execute permission to the sh file.

Comment: @ShivamVerma Alright.. but I'm not familiar with the shell script. Can you tell me how?

Comment: I'm not a mac user so not sure about. But on linux, it is `sudo chmod +x d2j_invoke.sh`

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You need to provide execute permissions to your sh script.

To do that : `sudo chmod +x d2j_invoke.sh`

Comment: I lost one hour over this. I gave the d2j-dex2jar.sh +x permission but I did not give it to invoke.sh Thank you!

Comment: **d2j-dex2jar.sh +x** this command also giving me the permission denied

Comment: @Min2 Did you give the permission to d2j_invoke.sh ?

Comment: Worked for me this way `sudo chmod +x ./d2j-dex2jar.sh classes.dex`

Answer (score 22):

Still If you find no luck use,

`chmod a+x *.sh`

Comment: Good to know :)